# RPM build - %prep not considered (user not created)

Tags: rpmbuild

I've created a rpm where in spec file in %prep I create user and group, so the new installed files do run under that specific user. However, looks like rpmbuild ignores my %prep and during rpm installation im gettin:

```
Running Transaction
  Installing : appdynamics-machineagent-4.0.1.0-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1/1 
warning: user appdynamics does not exist - using root
warning: group appdynamics does not exist - using root
warning: user appdynamics does not exist - using root
warning: group appdynamics does not exist - using root
```

RPM gets installed but with root user. My spec file (%prep section) looks like this:

```
%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0
%prep
getent group appdynamics >/dev/null || groupadd -r appdynamics || exit 1
getent passwd appdynamics >/dev/null || useradd -r -g appdynamics -d /opt/appdynamics -s /bin/sh -c "appdynamics system user" appdynamics || exit 1
if [ -x /etc/init.d/appdynamics ]
then
  /etc/init.d/appdynamics stop || true
fi
if [ -d /opt/appdynamics ]
then
  rm -rf /opt/appdynamics || true
fi
exit 0
%setup -q
%build
%install
......
%files
%defattr(-,appdynamics,appdynamics)
%dir /opt/appdynamics
......
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks a zillion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%prep` preps the *build*. It's not run on the client machine. You want it in `%pre` or `%post` to run at install.

Comment: Then please upvote the answer and check it as correct.

Comment: checked as correct. however i can't vote yet: "vote up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: LOL. Still glad I could help! ;)